# Generic NamedTuple in Crystal

Tags: crystal-lang

Is there a way to use NamedTuple as Generics? Something like:

```
alias JsonCommand = NamedTuple(T){
  name : String
  data : T
}

command : JsonCommand(String) = { name: "some command", data: "some data" }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

The main reason why named tuples exist in the language is for implementing named arguments.

For every other use case it's recommended to use a struct instead and it can be used with generics.

```
record JSONCommand(T), name : String, data : T

command = JSONCommand.new(name: "some command", data: "some data")
```

Comment: Thanks, the issue with record is that `command.to_json` throws an error. Is there a way to convert it to json automatically without writing jsom mapping?

Comment: Simply include `JSON::Serializable`. https://carc.in/#/r/88m1